# Racy behavior in low-latency interrupt-based transmit code

Tags: c, embedded, race-condition

Suppose you have some data transmitting peripheral, like a UART, that signals an interrupt whenever it's ready to transmit more data. We're sending data from a circular buffer, where `tail` is where the data is removed from, `head` is where you add data, and `tail == head` means that there's no more data to transmit.

Let's also assume that the peripheral has no buffering whatsoever, and you can't pass it the next value to send while it's busy sending the current one. If you need a concrete, if made-up, example, think of a shift register attached directly to a CPU's parallel I/O port.

To keep transmitter as busy as possible, you might wish to transmit as soon as the transmit interrupt handler is entered. When there's no data to transmit, the interrupt is masked out and the handler will not be invoked even though the interrupt has been armed. The system starts in with the interrupt masked out.

I'll use C to illustrate things, although the issue is not C-specific. The interrupt handler, and the buffer, are set up as follows:

```
char buf[...];
char * head = buf;                     ///< write pointer
char * tail = buf;                     ///< read pointer
char * const first = buf;              ///< first byte of the buffer
char * const last = buf+sizeof(buf)-1; ///< last byte of the buffer

/// Sends one byte out. The interrupt handler will be invoked as soon
/// as another byte can be sent.
void transmit(char);     

void handler() {
  transmit(*tail);
  if (tail == last)
    tail = first;
  else
    tail++;
  if (tail == head)
    mask_interrupt();
}
```

So far, so good. Now let's see how one might implement `putch()`.  We can invoke `putch()` in bursts much faster than the device is able to send the data out. Let's assume that the caller knows not to overflow the buffer.

```
void putch(char c) {
  *head = c;
  if (head == last)
    head = first;
  else
    head++;
  /***/
  unmask_interrupt();
}
```

Suppose now that these things happen:

1. The transmitter was busy, and when `putch` was called, there a byte was being sent.
2. The transmission happens to finish when `putch` is in the spot marked `/***/` above. The `handler()` happens to execute right there.
3. The `handler()` happens to send the last byte of the data in the buffer - the byte that we have just loaded in preceding lines in `putch()`.

The handler masks the interrupt, as there's no more data to send, but `putch` incorrectly unmasks it right after `handler()` returns. Thus the `handler` will have another go through the buffer, and will send a buffer's worth of stale data until `tail` equals `head` again.

My questions is: **Is the only fix to increase the latency and check for empty buffer before sending in the `handler`?** The fixed code looks as follows:

```
void fixed_handler() {
  if (head == tail) {
    mask_interrupt();
    arm_interrupt(); // so that next time we unmask it, we get invoked
    return;
  }
  transmit(*tail);
  if (tail == last)
    tail = first;
  else
    tail++;
}
```

This fix adds some latency, and also adds an extra operation (`arm_interrupt`) that's executed once when there's no more data to send.

For possible other approaches, feel free to assume the existence of at least the following operations:

```
/// Is the interrupt armed and will the handler fire once unmasked?
bool is_armed();
/// Is the interrupt unmasked?
bool is_unmasked();
```

Comment: That's a classical race condition.

Comment: Use atomics updates.

Comment: @Olaf The cost of almost any solution to this problem is, in my particular case, equivalent - that's why I'm looking for multiple solutions. But sometimes that cost, even though equivalent in wall clock terms, is not acceptable. On my particular architecture, atomic updates are non-preemptible and they'll increase latency on other parts of the system that have already essentially exhausted their latency budget. This question is essentially a fishing expedition: I have had the fix since day one (the race is hypothetical), but wonder if it's the only fix.

Answer (score 2):

I've always done this with double-buffering, so that at any point in time the program and the UART are "owning" different buffers.

When the UART finishes sending its buffer, a swap can happen, with interrupts masked.
That way, it doesn't have to mask interrupts on every character.

Comment: Translating this to the architecture above, I think what you're saying is that `putch` should not touch the head, but some temporary pointer, and then the `head` update can be done when the last `putch` of a bunch has been done - then it's done atomically with the transmit interrupt disabled.

Comment: @KubaOber: I wouldn't even have them working out of the same space. Isn't it just as easy to have two buffers, and when the UART gets to the end of one, just swap buffer pointers? That way, you don't need head and tail pointers, just a "next character" index in each buffer.

Comment: I'm trying to keep using one buffer. That's the goal of this. I'm using all free RAM for the buffers, down to last byte, so doubling the number of buffers would halve the buffer space... and leave plenty of buffer bytes unused. No dynamic memory allocation is done in any of the code, it's hard-realtime PLC-like stuff. I'm using the circular buffers to assemble the transmit data on the fly, without any intervening storage.

Comment: With two buffers, I'd always have to wait for an entire buffer to be free to start using it. Here I only need two empty bytes to keep going. Yours is a valid approach, but doesn't work in my scenario :(

Comment: @KubaOber: Surely you know best, but I've just used two 256-byte buffers instead of one 512-byte buffer. They could be as small as 8 and 16 or even 1 and 2. Overall, you can't send any faster than the UART can go, so all the buffer does is give the sender some slack. And the waiting is not for a free buffer, it is after you've filled your buffer and the other is not yet empty. Something has to block you because the UART is a bottleneck - your object is to keep it busy, not to keep your program busy. Good luck.

Comment: "the waiting is not for a free buffer, it is after you've filled your buffer and the other is not yet empty" Isn't one synonymous with the other? I mean, we wait prior to the flip for the hardware-facing buffer to be free. I want to make sure I understood you right.

Comment: @KubaOber: With your head-tail scheme, where the process is much faster than the UART, won't you almost always be in the situation where the buffer is full and your process is waiting for a byte to be removed by the UART, so you have to wait anyway. It's just a question of whether you want to wait on every byte, or wait for a bigger chunk. I prefer the latter, as having less per-byte overhead. But as I said - it's your ballgame :)

Answer (score 0):

One fix would be to prevent the interrupt handler from running within `putch`:

```
void putch(char c) {
  *head = c;
  mask_interrupt();
  if (head == last)
    head = first;
  else
    head++;
  unmask_interrupt();
}
```

This lets us use the original transmit-first interrupt handler. The problem with that is that overall it increases the number of operations performed per byte sent. It also increases the peak latency as well, since there are now times when `handler()` simply won't run even though the hardware is ready for more data *and* there's data to be sent.

The average latency in getting the transmitter busy again is determined by the interrupt handler. The peak latency on top of that is determined by the code that delays the execution of the interrupt handler.